Как быстро узнать тип данных поля в таблице SQL Server
Как определить тип данных поля в таблице SQL с помощью запроса, не просматривая структуру вручную
я делаю так

Сначала нахожу нужную таблицу из списка всех таблиц
Затем ищу необходимое поле среди множества других полей в этой таблице...

а как можно это сделать быстрее?

Предлагаю использовать следующий SQL-запрос
Schema Views
MYDATABASEACTIVE - замените на ту базу, с которой работаете
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
FROM MYDATABASEACTIVE.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'ИМЯ_ВАШЕЙ_ТАБЛИЦЫ' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'ИМЯ_ВАШЕГО_ПОЛЯ';

он вернет информацию о типе данных поля и его длине, что позволит вам быстрее получить нужную информацию без необходимости вручную просматривать структуру таблицы

Тогда посмотрите лучше на sys.columns и прочие рядомлежащие.. INFORMATION_SCHEMA - это предопределённый набор представлений на базе системных таблиц, который поддерживается многими СУБД. Но многое и не попадает туда.

@Akina, а если вам надо быстро найти поле из таблицы и его тип и длину (ну если вы знаете приблизительно, что варшар, чтоб длину тоже выдал) как вы это делаете???

... С учётом, что таблиц много и в каждой таблице много полей...

Если таблицу можно найти быстро, потому как они в алфавитном порядке, Поля же в таблицах записаны в разброс (может, по мере создания полей(? ) ), и искать нужное поле из множества... Забирает время

а если вам надо быстро найти поле из таблицы ... как вы это делаете??? указываю нужные имена (схемы, таблицы, поля) во WHERE... ORDER BY опять же никто не запрещал.
